# Hot to register already constructed instance in unity?

Tags: .net, unity-container

I'm try to construct HttpClient before register it in unity, but it fails at runtime with error message says HttpMessageHandler not accessible.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:3721");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterInstance<HttpClient>(client);
IUnityContainer newcontainer = new UnityContainer();
HttpClient newclient = newcontainer.Resolve<HttpClient>();
```

It seems unity create another HttpClient instance using the constructor which have the most arguments.

```
HttpClient(HttpMessageHandler handler, bool disposeHandler);
```

HttpMessageHandler is abstract class, so I think this the problem my code fails at runtime.
So, How can I control unity to use which construct or is there a way to that unity use already constructed instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It seems unity create another HttpClient instance using the constructor which have the most arguments.

Yes, by default Unity uses the constructor with the biggest signature.

> So, How can I control unity to use which constructor?

Using InjectionConstructor: `newContainer.RegisterType<HttpClient>(new InjectionConstructor());`
This tells Unity to use the parameterless constructor.

> or is there a way to that unity use already constructed instance?

With RegisterInstance: `container.RegisterInstance<HttpClient>(client);`

---

### WARNING

If you create a new container, this one does not share registrations with the first one:

```
MyObject instance = new MyObject();
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterInstance<MyObject>(instance);

Assert.AreSame(instance, container.Resolve<MyObject>());

IUnityContainer newcontainer = new UnityContainer();
Assert.AreNotSame(instance, newcontainer.Resolve<MyObject>());
```

Comment: ,thanks. About the thrid question,I do use container.RegisterInstance, but I think unity still new a instance rather than use the exist one.

Comment: Unity will give you the same instance if you resolve against the SAME container. See my updated answer

Comment: I think I did not decribe the problem clearly, but your solution give me another way. thanks.