# Need some advice about the correct way to write own httpclient interface

Tags: .net, wpf, async-await

I want create a WPF application to connect to my web api server. But I'm newbie in WPF. More worse,even in .net.

Actually, I already get things to work, follow this http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-wpf-application.

After more search,I found that I totally work on a wrong way(winform way).And it seems that I should use MVVM style as most communites said. So I decide to rewrite all my code.

I use prism to create a module, and bind name and password to the ViewModel class. Now I can get name and password from Textbox.

First, I failed to create a httpclient instance for every ViewModel to use. below is the problem links

[Hot to register already constructed instance in unity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16371202/hot-to-register-already-constructed-instance-in-unity)

So I deicide to write like this. First create the interface.

```
public interface IData
{
    IEnumerable<device> getDevicesByUser(user user);
    IEnumerable<user> getUsers();
    currentUser getCurrentUserInfo();
}
```

and a implement interface

```
public class HttpService : IData
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    public HttpService()
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:3721");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    }

    public IEnumerable<device> getDevicesByUser(user user)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IEnumerable<user> getUsers()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public currentUser getCurrentUserInfo()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Later, I can register instance in the unity, and can use it in every ViewModel.But the situation is I can't go any further. I use two method,but neither can works. I need advice about the correct way.

the fisrt way. I write async methods for each interface method.

```
public currentUser getCurrentUserInfo()
    {
      return getCurrentUserInfoFromServer();
    }

private async void getCurrentUserInfoFromServer()
    {
        try
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync("api/user");
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); 
            var currentuser = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<currentUser>();
        }
        catch (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonException jEx)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(jEx.Message);
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {

        }
    }
```

But it seems async can not return type other than void and task. And it seems weird.
So I try to write all request to one method.

```
private async void getData(string requestUri)
    {
        try
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync("api/user"+requestUri);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var ? = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<?>();
        }
        catch (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonException jEx)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(jEx.Message);
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {

        }
    }
```

this codes still have the same problem like the first one. Can not return type other than void and task, and another problem is how to get data dynamic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Async methods should almost always return `Task` or `Task<T>`, because that's what being asynchronous means: the method returns almost immediately, but it hasn't actually completed yet. So, to get its result, you `await` the returned `Task`. So, your method would look something like this:

```
private async Task<CurrentUser> GetCurrentUserInfoFromServerAsync()
{
    try
    {
        var response = await client.GetAsync("api/user");
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); 
        var currentuser = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<currentUser>();
        return currentUser; // sets the result of the returned Task
    }
    catch (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonException jEx)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(jEx.Message);
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

This means the method that calls `GetCurrentUserInfoFromServerAsync()` also needs to be `async`, and the method that that, etc., all the way to the top.

Also, it's a good practice to separate your concerns: your `HttpService` should not show `MessabeBox`es and instead just let the exceptions propagate out of the method. You should leave dealing with the UI to higher layers.